# ejabberd application controller syntax error before log_rotate_size

Tags: ejabberd, freebsd

I manage to compile ejabberd 17-01 from source on FreeBSD 11 (guest on Mac's VirtualBox) as "root".

So I login as "ejabberd" and try to run "ejabberdctl foreground". Then, I got the following error:
ejabberd application controller syntax error before log_rotate_size

Any idea? Thank you for you help!

Comment: Also fyi, I have looked at my /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml, line where log_rotate_size is and "clean up" and blank spaces.

Comment: Just now I moved my-ejabberd dir to ejabberd (user) directory.
And chown -R ejabberd /usr/home/ejabberd/my-ejabberd/{lib,lock,log}
And still error persist.